# How to remove the decimal point from string c#

Tags: c#

I want to remove decimal point from string.

I try with this code but not work for me:

```
string wSpeed = Math.Round(weatherBindingData.WeatherDataCurrent.Wind.Speed) * 3.6 + "km/h";
WindSpeed.Text = wSpeed;
```

I want to remove the decimal point, but with this code I receive a values with decimal point.

How is the correct way to remove the decimal point?

Comment: Use formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Use formatting:

```
string wSpeed = $"{Math.Round(weatherBindingData.WeatherDataCurrent.Wind.Speed) * 3.6:0}km/h";
```

Or what you more likely want:

```
string wSpeed = $"{weatherBindingData.WeatherDataCurrent.Wind.Speed * 3.6:0}km/h";
```